# Function to Flip Array Values to Array Keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a php function which can take the below array

```
array (size=4)
 1 => string '0' 
 6 => string '1' 
 7 => string '1' 
 8 => string '7'
```

And flip it to the below array notice that an array must have unique key values so can we flip the array where value 1 = key values 6, 7

```
array (size=3)
 0 => string '1' 
 1 => string '6, 7'
 7 => string '8'
```

Comment: @splash58 not quite. `array_flip` won't concatenate keys that have the same value..

Comment: There is no such function, you'll need to write it yourself. Good Luck!

Comment: If you just searched same question title on google you will see php manual for array_flip function

Comment: @MohamedBelal It is not quite array_flip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$arr = array ( 1 => '0', 6 => '1', 7 => '1', 8 => '7' );

// Find unique values of array and make them as keys
$res = array_flip($arr);
// Find keys from sourse array with value of key in new array
foreach($res as $k =>$v) $res[$k] = implode(", ", array_keys($arr, $k));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6, 7
    [7] => 8
)
```

Comment: Nice little explanation and nice use of `array_keys()` with `implode()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 Even a cat likes a kind word :)

Comment: @Rizier123 What you say about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30795697/2899618)

Answer (score 4):

You can try it as

Simply use `foreach` and interchange the values of `key` with `values`

```
$arr = array ( 1 => '0', 6 => '1', 7 => '1', 8 => '7' );
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $result[$value][] = $key;
}
print_r($result);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://eval.in/380281)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not an existing, but you can write your's custom as per need, see the below function does exact what you need:

```
function customFlip($arr){
    $newArray = array();
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($value, $newArray)) {
                if (empty($newArray[$value])) {
                    $newArray[$value] = $key;
                } else {
                    $newArray[$value] .= ','.$key;
                }
            } else {
                $newArray[$value] = $key;
            }
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is a function called array_flip